# How to separate clustered marker on last "cluster click"

Tags: javascript, maps, leaflet, markerclusterer

I'm trying to show markers separately when I click on a cluster.
I'm using `Leaflet.markercluster` plugin.

For example:

[image]

Those markers aren't really so close and I have to show them in their real coordinates. I have this problem even if I'm not in maxZoom. How can I do it?

**EDIT**

This is cluster initialization:

```
var clustern = L.markerClusterGroup({
    iconCreateFunction: function (cluster) {
        return L.divIcon({
            html: "<div style='margin-left: -20px; margin-top: -20px; width: 40px; height: 40px;' class='leaflet-marker-icon marker-cluster marker-cluster-medium '><div><span>"
                  + cluster.getChildCount() + "</span></div></div>",
        })
    },
    zoomToBoundsOnClick: true,
    animate: true,
    spiderLegPolylineOptions: {opacity: 0},
    maxClusterRadius: 80,
    spiderfyOnMaxZoom: false,
    showCoverageOnHover: false
});
```

This is how markers are added:

```
$.get('csv/Export.csv', function (csvContent) {
    localarr = csvContent.split("\n").map(function (row) {
        return row.split(",");
    })
    localarr.forEach(function (riga, index) {
        if (index > 0) {
            clustern.addLayer(L.marker(L.latLng(riga[74], riga[75])));
            map.addLayer(clustern)
        }
    })
    console.log(localarr)
})
```

Comment: When you say "last click" do you mean "long click"?

Comment: I mean that after clicking, individual markers are shown instead of the cluster, like on image.

Comment: Can you post some code? In order to do it in the best way, you can find good advices here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I edited the question. Anyway, if I click on a cluster that show some markers and another cluster, those markers are at rigth coordinates, for this I have specified "last cluster click"